# How to declare a generic tuple?

Tags: scala

The specialized data type can be declared, but there are no "intermediary specialization" for tuples... Exists?

Illustration:

```
 val ingredients1 : Seq[(String,Int)] = Seq(("sugar",4),("flour",9))  // high specialization
 val ingredients2 : Seq[(Any,Any)] = Seq(("sugar",4),("flour",9))  // ... near ...
 val ingredients3 : Seq[(Any,Any,Any)] = Seq(("sugar",4,true),("flour",9,false))  // ...near

 // low specialization: can be wrong type
 val ingredients4 : Seq[Any] = Seq(("sugar",4),("flour",9))  // is a tuple, ok...
 val ingredients4 : Seq[(Any)] = Seq(("sugar",4),("flour",9))  // is a tuple, ok...

 val wrong1: Seq[(Any)] = Seq("sugar",4)  // it is not a tuple!
 val wrong2 : Seq[Any] = Seq("sugar",4)  // it is not a tuple!
```

I need a "generic type",  a kind of "AnySeqOfTypes", that matches `(Any,Any,Any)`, `(Any,Any)` and `(Any)`, but **say error** for non-tuples in this kind of function:

```
  def helloTuple(aTuple: Seq[AnySeqOfTypes]) : Unit = println("Hello tuple: "+aTuple)
```

---

PS: tested with Scala v2.11.8, but answer/comments can be Scala 2.13 or more.

Comment: Tuples are already generic. Either all the tuples of in a same seq have same type params (w/ parametrized `helloTuple`), or you will face erasure issue or heterogenous seq.

Comment: How are you going to use this type? Printing is easy, but if you are going to access any of the fields you need to know how many there are.

Comment: @Tim I need to iterate over each item *x(i)* of the Seq, and do something as `x(i).productIterator.foreach({
    case s: String => ("<q>" + s+"</q>")
    case k: Any => (k.toString)
})
`

Comment: It looks like you would be better off using a custom `case class(String, Int, Option[Boolean])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Product:

```
def helloTuple(aTuple: Seq[Product]) : Unit = println("Hello tuple: "+aTuple)
```

This gives you productIterator, as you requested in a comment:

```
def helloTuple(aTuple: Seq[Product]) : Unit = 
  aTuple.head.productIterator.foreach {
    case s: String => "<q>" + s + "</q>"
    case k: Any => k.toString
  }
```

Note that Product also includes case classes. That said, please don't use the above code as-is to generate HTML, as it is likely vulnerable to XSS.

Comment: Thanks Brian, is working (!). The only case with problem is the singular tuple, `Seq[(String)]`.

Comment: @Peter `Seq[(String)]` is not a Seq of the singular tuple; that's written `Seq[Tuple1[String]]` and created like `Seq(Tuple1(""))`.

Comment: How to declare it?  For example `val t : Tuple1[Int] = Tuple1(22)`   is valid, but `val tt : Seq(Tuple1[Int]) = Seq(Tuple1(22))` is error... Strange error *"';' expected but '(' found"*.

Comment: @Peter the type should be `Seq[Tuple1[String]]`.